# I'm trying to add RevitAPI.dll and RevitAPIU.dll as references in the visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, revit-api

I did everything as recommended "widely known" but when I start debugging this message is shown:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in Unknown Module.
Could not load file or assembly 'RevitAPIUI, Version=24.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

How can I solve this problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which operating system?  This can happen if you load a Windows DLL on Linux or vice versa, or load an x86 DLL on an ARM system.

Answer (score 0):

If you really followed the getting started instructed in the My First Plugin video tutorial and the Revit developer guind Hello World samples, the only explanation I can think of is a corruption of your Revit installation.